react-query useMutation does not update new changes on the UI
I have a React 18 app. I am using @tanstack/react-query, version 5 for state management.
Firstly, when I click the like button, my UI does not change. Typical behavior should be that the number of likes should increase by one.

Secondly, when I reload my page I get the below errors in my browser console and my browser view is blank.

Not sure, what I am doing wrong here.
Below is my code:
App.jsx file:
import { useState } from "react";
import MenuBar from "./components/MenuBar";
import Notification from "./components/Notification";
import BlogsPage from "./pages/BlogsPage";
import LoginPage from "./pages/LoginPage";
import UsersPage from "./pages/UsersPage";
import { Route, Routes, useMatch } from "react-router-dom";
import User from "./components/User";
import { useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import Blog from "./components/Blog";

const App = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const allBlogs = queryClient.getQueryData(['blogs']);
  const allUsers = queryClient.getQueryData(['users']);

  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const userMatch = useMatch("/users/:id");
  console.log('userMatch', userMatch);
  const singleUserInfo = userMatch
    ? allUsers.find(user => user.id === userMatch.params.id)
    : null;
  console.log('singleUserInfo', singleUserInfo);

  const blogMatch = useMatch("/blogs/:id");
  console.log('blogMatch', blogMatch);
  const singleBlogInfo = blogMatch
    ? allBlogs.find(blog => blog.id === blogMatch.params.id)
    : null;
  console.log('singleBlogInfo', singleBlogInfo);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Blogs App</h1>

      <MenuBar setUsername={setUsername} setPassword={setPassword} />

      <Notification />

      <LoginPage 
        username={username} 
        password={password} 
        setUsername={setUsername} 
        setPassword={setPassword} 
      />

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/users/:id" element={<User user={singleUserInfo} />} />
        <Route path="/blogs/:id" element={<Blog blog={singleBlogInfo} />} />
        <Route path="/users" element={<UsersPage />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<BlogsPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

Blog.jsx file:
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { useNotificationDispatch } from "../context/NotificationContext";
import blogService from "../services/blogs";
import { removeNotificationAfterFiveSeconds, setNotification } from "../helper/notificationSetOrRemove";
import { useUserValue } from "../context/UserContext";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Blog = ({ blog }) => {
  console.log('Blog.jsx', blog);

  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const notificationDispatch = useNotificationDispatch();
  const userLoggedIn = useUserValue();
  
  const updateBlogMutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: blogService.updateBlog,
    // mutationFn: (blog) => blogService.updateBlog(blog),
    onSuccess: (updatedBlog) => {
      // queryClient.invalidateQueries('blogs');
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['blogs'] }, updatedBlog);
    },
    onError: (error, blogData) => {
      console.error(`UPDATE MUTATION ERROR: ${error.message}`);
      setNotification(notificationDispatch, `UPDATE MUTATION ERROR: Blog '${blogData.title}' was already removed from server`, true);
      removeNotificationAfterFiveSeconds(notificationDispatch);
    }
  });

  const handleIncreaseLikes = () => {
    updateBlogMutation.mutate({ ...blog, likes: blog.likes + 1 });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 data-testid="title">{blog.title}</h1>
      <h4 data-testid="author">Author: {blog.author}</h4>

      <div data-testid="url">
        <Link to={blog.url} target="_blank">{blog.url}</Link>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <span data-testid="likes">Likes: {blog.likes}</span>
            <button onClick={handleIncreaseLikes} className="likeBtn">
              like
            </button>
          </div>

          <div data-testid="addedBy">Added by: {blog.user.name}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

Blog.propTypes = {
  blog: PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.string,
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    author: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    url: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    likes: PropTypes.number,
    user: PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      username: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }),
  }),
};

export default Blog;

/src/services/blogs.js file:
import axios from 'axios';
const baseUrl = '/api/blogs';

const updateBlog = async (updatedBlog) => {
  const response = await axios.put(`${baseUrl}/${updatedBlog.id}`, updatedBlog);
  return response.data;
};

export default { updateBlog };

BlogList.jsx file:
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import blogService from "../services/blogs";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const BlogsList = () => {
  // styles
  const blogStyle = {
    padding: 5,
    border: "solid",
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 5,
  };

  // get all blogs
  const { isLoading, isError, data: blogsData, error } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['blogs'],
    queryFn: blogService.getAllBlogs,
    select: (blogs) => blogs.sort((a, b) => b.likes - a.likes),
    retry: false,
  });
  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>loading data...</div>;
  }
  if (isError) {
    return (
      <>
        <div>blogs service not available due to: {error.message}.</div>
        <div>Unable to get all blogs</div>
      </>
    );
  }
  // console.log('blogsData', blogsData);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul style={{ listStyleType: "none", padding: 0 }}>
        {blogsData.map((blog) => (
          <li key={blog.id} style={blogStyle} className="blog">
            <Link to={`/blogs/${blog.id}`}>{blog.title}</Link> - <span>{blog.author}</span>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BlogsList;


You aren't using the react query correctly. Specifically you should either be using a loader in your route, or you should be using a useQuery in a routed component to query the data that is keyed to they query you're invalidating in the mutation. Refer to the documentation

useQueryClient is not reactive to any query data changing. The standard way is to call useQuery to retrieve any data (which handles caching automatically).
const allBlogs = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['blogs'],
    queryFn: () => {/* make request to get blog data*/}
}).data;


I am already doing this in the BlogList.jsx file. I have updated my code above.

@qqq But your App component still won't be reactive to changes in the data because it's using useQueryClient instead of useQuery.

I moved the useQuery code from BlogList.jsx to App.jsx. I also removed the useQueryClient from App.jsx and added that to BlogList.jsx instead. Everything seems to be working correctly now. Thank you!

I understand now that if I want a reactive behavior I should always use useQuery. But if I am using the same api request in two different files with useQuery, that does not seem to be efficient. Is there any best practice that I need to follow here?

If you're using the same api request in two different files you should DEFINITELY be using useQuery (and using the same query key in both places) that is exactly the use case this library was made to solve.

@qqq Like Chad S. wrote, calling useQuery in both components is perfectly valid. You just need to configure caching behavior to ensure there won't be multiple requests and the rest is handled by the library: this is one of the main reasons for using React Query in the first place.
